# Not able to prevent concurrent file access in webservice using locks

Tags: asp.net, web-services, serialization, concurrency, locking

I have created a webservice(.asmx) that is called using ajax on the page load event of every page . it is basically used to record website user behavior. I am serializing this captured information into an xml file. This is the method im using.

```
    public static void SerializeObject<T>(T serializableObject, string fileName)
    {

            if (serializableObject == null) { return; }

            try
            {
                XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(serializableObject.GetType());
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(stream, serializableObject);
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    xmlDocument.Load(stream);
                    xmlDocument.Save(fileName);
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log exception here
            }

    }
    public static T DeSerializeObject<T>(string fileName)
    {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) { return default(T); }

            T objectOut = default(T);

            try
            {
                XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDocument.Load(fileName);
                string xmlString = xmlDocument.OuterXml;

                using (StringReader read = new StringReader(xmlString))
                {
                    Type outType = typeof(T);

                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(outType);
                    using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(read))
                    {
                        objectOut = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                        reader.Close();
                    }

                    read.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log exception here
            }

            return objectOut;

    }

    public static List<UserPath> saveandfetch<T>(string sord, string filename, T serializableObject=default(T))
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            if (sord == "S")
            {
                List<UserPath> up = serializableObject as List<UserPath>;
                SerializeObject<List<UserPath>>(up, filename);
                return null;
            }
            else if (sord == "D")
            {
                List<UserPath> up = DeSerializeObject<List<UserPath>>(filename);
                return up;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Th third function is used to both serialize and de-serialize by calling the correct functions.I have placed a lock on this function. But the problem is even after this when two or more users browse at the same time the data is getting overwritten.

I am calling the function like this:

```
  List<UserPath> UPL = saveandfetch<List<UserPath>>("D",Server.MapPath("/UserPath.xml"));//deserialize

  saveandfetch<List<UserPath>>("S",Server.MapPath("/UserPath.xml"),UPL); //serialize
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does locker is a static object of type 'Object'?

Comment: no its not a static object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order lock properly your locker object should be declared as:

```
static object locker = new object();
```

that way it will be created only once and used across all function calls.